# How to submit iPhone application which only supports iphone 6 & 6+

Tags: objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect

I'm developing an application that only supported for iPhone 6 & 6+ with iOS 8 or later. I got this problem while trying to submit the app

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format

How can I let iTune Connect know that iPhone 6 & 6+ with 4.7" & 5.5" do not require 120x120 app icon. Does anyone meet this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not allow shipping apps that require an iPhone 6/6+.

You must make your app compatible with the iPhone 4s/5/5s.

Comment: My app uses Apple Pay with TouchID. So how can I restrict other device from downloading the app from store?

Comment: Apple Pay doesn't require an iPhone 6/6+. According to this press release, next year Apple will be "extending Apple Pay to over 200 million owners of iPhone 5, iPhone 5c and iPhone 5s worldwide." -- https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/09/09Apple-Announces-Apple-Pay.html

Comment: For iPhone 4s users, who won't ever be able to use Apple Pay, I guess your only option is to let them use your app but not purchase anything. You can't stop them from downloading it, in fact if they have an iPhone 6 and an iPhone 4s then it will automatically be downloaded to the 4s, and you must provide an app icon.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. So can I upload some fake screen shots for 4" & 3.5" devices in other to make iTune Connect happy?

Comment: No... you should upload real screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore this warning and submit directly. Mention the compatibility in your app description. Me too faced same issue and submitted that without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for your advice