# Exclusive iPhone 6 app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-6

Is it possible to submit an app from Xcode through iTunes Connect for only an iPhone 6 and if it is how do you do it?

I have tried to submit it already by just including screenshots for iPhone 6 but it would not go through because it said that iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 configurations had to be supported.

Comment: Nope. You must support all devices. You can only limit on iOS version and possibly hardwar features.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. When you submit an application for iPhones, it must be for ALL iPhones. Sorry. You can see [How to submit iPhone application which only supports iphone 6 & 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121977/how-to-submit-iphone-application-which-only-supports-iphone-6-6) for more information, but this question is a duplicate.